# Inbuilt method to convert a whole Pandas dataframe of same dtype into a python set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, set

I have a pandas dataframe containing only dates like this

[image]

Is there an inbuilt way to convert the whole dataframe into a python set, rather than writing some for loops, without any headers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
set(df.to_numpy().flatten())
```

It first views your data as a 1D array, then creates a set from that.

Comment: There is one subtlety though, this will convert all the timestamps to numpy.datetime64. To keep pandas Timestamp, try something like `set(df.melt()['value'])`

Comment: @psarka: Good point, assuming the DataFrame contains actual timestamps and not strings.